# Is there a way to set my form options app-wide in Symfony3?

Tags: forms, symfony

For example, I want all my 'DateType' fields to be widget `single_text` with format `dd/mm/yyyy`. How to set those as the default options for my app?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `BaseDateType` class with the following content:

```
class BaseDateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return DateType::class;
    }
}
```

Then use `BaseDateType` in your forms, and you can still override options if you need.